# Using class as extend of the Entity, but it is not the physical table in the model

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, inheritance

I am not sure if title of the post is understandable, but I will try to explain it with examples.
The main class is the entity, lets name it Animal

```
@Entity
public class Animal {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  
  private String param1;
}
```

The `param1` is some basic property which only extended classes will expose what it represents:

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
  public String getName() {
    return super.getParam1();
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    super.setParam1(name);
  }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
  public String getBreed() {
    return super.getParam1();
  }
  public void setBreed(String breed) {
    super.setParam1(breed);
  }
}
```

When creating a new object of `Cat` and trying to save it, I get the error `Unknown entity: com.example.Cat`.
I have read about persistence inheritance but I think this is not the case since mine extended classes are just some logic in the services and not the actual tables in the model.
Is there any solution on how I can save the superclass ?

Comment: Animal cat = new Cat(); ----> perform the operations and then save cat.
Is this what u r trying ? Or else please share the code of creating and saving object.

Comment: But with that I do not have access to the setters I have wrote in the Cat class

Comment: You can make Cat cat = new Cat(); , then use getters/setters or your logic ---> then convert it to Animal cat1 = cat; [with some logic] before saving.